# Jquery show div based on another div's visibility and checked value

Tags: jquery, css

I need to show/hide a div based on another div's input. Normally this is easy but this one is a headache.

HTML:

```
<div id="main-question">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-radios">
      <div class="radio">
        <label class="control-label"><input type="radio" name="ad" value="option1" class="form-radio" />option 1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio"> 
        <label class="control-label"><input type="radio" name="ad" value="option2" class="form-radio" />option 2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio"> 
        <label class="control-label"><input type="radio" name="ad" value="option3" checked="checked" class="form-radio" />option 3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-radios">
      <div class="radio">
        <label class="control-label"><input type="radio" name="ad" value="optiona" class="form-radio" />option a</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio"> 
        <label class="control-label"><input type="radio" name="ad" value="optionb" class="form-radio" />option b</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio"> 
        <label class="control-label"><input type="radio" name="ad" value="optionc" checked="checked" class="form-radio" />option c</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="next-form">
  <!-- code -->
</div>
```

There is a module that shows the group based on a drop-down select. This module creates a `display:none;` on all groups that aren't currently shown and a `display:block;` for the one that is visible. I have tried the following (and many iterations) with no luck:

```
    <script>
    (function ($) {
      $('#main-question .form-group').each(function() {
        if ( ($(this).css('display') === 'block') && ($(this).find('[type=radio]').val() !== '') ) {
          $('div#next-form').show(400);
        }
      });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

And I'm not sure how to fire this when the select box changes as well since it

Comment: where is the drop-down?

Comment: Please make a demo of this in jsFiddle.net.  You'll get more answers and will find a solution much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should check `radio` by `checked` status, not by value, as below:

```
if(RADIO.is(':checked')) { // do something }
```